# How to remove the same directories/names from two strings /list?

Tags: csh

I am writing a c-shell script, where I am grepping two different directories in two strings. I wanted to remove the name of the directories which are the same. I only want the unique directory among the two by leaving out the duplicate ones. I am little confused about how to do this.

There are some common directories present in sta_views and pnr_views strings. I am grepped both of them using ls -l command as seen above stored them. Now what I want to do is "first we can loop over sta_view and check if that exist in the pnr_view list and if no , then put them in a separate list , if yes , then do not do anything" Hope this helps to understand you my question. Thank You!

Please let me know the approach to do it,

```
set pnr_views = `(ls -l pnr/rep/signoff_pnr/ | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'\n)`
set sta_views = `(ls -l sta/rep/ | grep '^d' | grep -v common | grep -v signoff.all.SAVEDESIGN | awk '{print $9}'\n)`

foreach i ($sta_view) 
if [$i == $pnr_view] #just want to remove the list pnr_view from sta_view
then
echo ...
else
```

Here `sta_views` contains the directories that are present in `pnr_views`. How shall I remove the `pnr_views` directories from `sta_views`?

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do. Are you seeking to remove common prefixes of filenames? A very small example would help; it can be with made-up data. (Also, why tag with `tcl`? What language do you really want the answers in?)

Comment: Hi 

There are some common directories present in sta_views and pnr_views strings. I am grepped both of them using ls -l command as seen above stored them. 

Now what I want to do is "first we can loop over sta_view and check if that exist in the pnr_view list and if no , then put them in a separate list , if yes , then do not do anything" 

Hope this helps to understand you my question.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -v -f lines-to-subtract.txt all-lines.txt`.

Example:

```
#! /bin/bash

minuend=(a b c d e)
subtrahend=(c e)

grep -v -f <(printf '%s\n' "${subtrahend[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${minuend[@]}")
```

Comment: Hi 

There are some common directories present in sta_views and pnr_views strings. I am grepped both of them using ls -l command as seen above stored them. 

Now what I want to do is "first we can loop over sta_view and check if that exist in the pnr_view list and if no , then put them in a separate list , if yes , then do not do anything" 

Hope this helps to understand you my question.  Thank You!

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast It would be better to write the information into the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), I'll give you a Tcl answer. It has the advantage of working correctly even with weirdly named directories (especially including ones with spaces in the name).

```
# How to list directories in a directory, but just get their last name
proc listDirNamesIn {directory} {
    glob -directory $directory -type d -tails *
}

# This will contain all *unwanted* directory names as keys
# The . is ARBITRARY and quoted just for highlighting here
set exclude(common) "."
set exclude(signoff.all.SAVEDESIGN) "."
foreach d [listDirNamesIn pnr/rep/signoff_pnr/] {
    set exclude($d) "."
}

# Now we get the list of directories we're interested in, applying the filter
set found {}
foreach d [listDirNamesIn sta/rep/] {
    if {![info exists exclude($d)]} {
        lappend found $d
    }
}

# Print the sorted result
puts "Name of all the views are [lsort $found]"
```

There's a few ways to make the code shorter, especially in modern Tcl, but this is good enough.